# Send unknown number of files using Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I am now using Guzzle to send multiple files uploaded by users to another server.

From my understanding, we can send files using Guzzle by using this code:

```
'multipart' => [
    [
        'name'     => 'FileContents',
        'contents' => file_get_contents($path . $name),
        'filename' => $name
    ],
    [
        'name'     => 'FileInfo',
        'contents' => json_encode($fileinfo)
    ]
],
```

However, as the number of the files uploaded may not be the same and the code above can be used to send only one file. How can I send the unknown number of files using Guzzle? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the server you sending request to. Is it able to handle an array inside `FileContents` and `FileInfo`? Or something like `FileContents_1`, `FileContents_2`, `FileContents_N`? It depends on your server.

Anyway in Guzzle you can easily fill the array with a loop:

```
$multipart => []
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $multipart[] = [
        'name'     => 'FileContents[]',
        'contents' => fopen($path . $name, 'r'),
        'filename' => $name
    ];
    $multipart[] = [
        'name'     => 'FileInfo[]',
        'contents' => json_encode($fileinfo)
    ]
}
```

P.S.

Also it's better to use `fopen()` instead of `file_get_contents()`, because you don't need to read the files in your script, only to pass them to Guzzle.